# NSArrayController+cocoa binding + core data: get the selected row at application Launching

Tags: macos, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I'm using cocoa-binding, NSArrayController and core data.
Just after Launching, the application have to get the first item, i try this in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
1. Entity *ent = arrayManager.arrangedObjects[0];

2. Entity *ent = arrayManager.selectedObjects[0];
```

---> error saying that the array is empty. why ?

other thing that i don't understand is that when the application appear, in the tableView there's a selected row, but when i log this :

```
NSLog(@"selected row in applicationDidFinishLaunching = %li",self.TableViewController.tableView.selectedRow);
```

`log: -1` --> no row selected ! why ?

Comment: So `arrangedObjects` returns results but `selectedObjects` does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do a fetch on the ArrayController in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in order to see your Entities there. Try doing this before accessing anything from the ArrayController:

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
     NSError *error;
     [arrayManager fetchWithRequest:nil merge:NO error:&error];
     Entity *ent = arrayManager.arrangedObjects[0];
 }
```

Comment: that's work thank you, can you explain why have i to fech with a nil request to work ?

Comment: Absolutely. Passing nil just does the default request of the NSArrayController, as far as I can tell. I could be wrong, but that's just what I've seen to make it do the default request it does when it's loaded elsewhere. - Also, you technically should be doing some error handling when you do the request. fetchWithRequest:merge:error returns a BOOL.